# function names from config file in python

Tags: python, json, numpy

I have a JSON config file which tells me what kind of distribution to sample from. For example:

```
{ "parameter1" : { "distribution" : "exponential", "mean" = 5},
  "parameter2" : { "distribution" : "poisson", "mean" = 3} }
```

The list above can be exhaustive. I need have a function which will read this json file, and return the appropriate distribution to the calling code.

I tried using string concatenation and `eval()`, but that gives me the sample values directly.
I should be able to return the object/function to the calling function.

Can some one help me do it?

My attempt:

```
import numpy.random as random

def getDistribution(distribution, params):
    string= 'random.'+distribution
    return eval(string)(params["mean"])
```

This returns a value to me. Is there a way to return a handle to the actual distribution function like `random.exponential()` or `random.poisson()` which I can use in the function calling `getDistribution()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use getattr to return the method (which is an attribute of `random`):

```
def get_method(name):
    return getattr(random, name, None)

def get_distribution(method, params):
    return method(params['mean'])

method_name = 'exponential'
method = get_method(method_name)
if method:
    results = get_distribution(method, params)
else:
    raise AttributeError('No such method in random: {}'.format(method_name))
```

`getattr` takes an optional third argument which is the value to return when the attribute cannot be found. I am using this to explicitly return `None`.  You can change that to a default method that you want to use if the chosen method name is not available.

Comment: so for my purpose, I can just use the `getattr()` and return the method pointer (if I can use that term) and in the calling function I can make use of the return value to get the actual sample! Thank you @burhan

Comment: In Python, methods are just like variables so can assign them to another name. Since methods are also attributes of classes, you can fetch them using getattr. They are not _pointers_ as you might be used to from other languages.